# Why did Harry not practice non-verbal spells after the end of 6th year of Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

Why did Harry Potter not practice non verbal spells following the sixth year of Hogwarts when he was staying in the Dursleys House?

Answer (score 5):

Because he was still underage,had the Ministry's trace on him and doing magic in a muggle neighbourhood would have got him in trouble with the law

note that he already had a warning letter in his 2nd year and had almost got prosecuted in his 5th year (although he was cleared of all charges)

edit: this question possibly arose due to the movie. I am not sure what the movie description is like but in the book it is pretty clear why he could not practice magic of any kind while at the Dursley's house

Comment: Yeah, the movies are pretty misleading: On the third one they actually start with Harry using the lumos charm in his room.

Answer (score 2):

## Because he still had the trace

The Ministry of Magic applies this piece of magic called 'The Trace' which can be used to detect when an underage wizard performs magic.  This obviously isn't used in Hogwarts, but it is used in settings where muggles are likely to be present, such as the Dursley's house, or anywhere really outside of Hogwarts.  Now, irrespective of the spell being verbal or non-verbal **the trace can still detect the magic has been performed by an underage wizard!** Therefore Harry didn't perform any non-verbal magic whilst with the Dursleys following his sixth year at Hogwarts simply because the Ministry of Magic, which was at that time corrupted by the Death Eaters, would have pounced on him!  Only when wizards reach the age of maturity is the trace removed!

Comment: then why didnt he decided to stay in Ron House .

Comment: @SohamJoshi it is used anywhere *outside of Hogwarts*: if any wizard or witch performs magic outside of their school, then they will be prosecuted by the Ministry!

Comment: Harry was still a minor, I'm not sure he had much choice where he stayed...

Comment: @SohamJoshi the other fact is that Harry was still under the protection of the enchantments of the Dursley's house; as soon as he left that he was a sitting duck!

Comment: FYI, I'm fairly certain if he could have stayed at the Weasleys then he'd be allowed to do magic inside the home. I remember something from somewhere about magic inside magical homes being okay and just left to the parents to handle. Thus Malfoy and his knowledge of curses and other DADA magic. However, unless someone has the source don't take my word as law.

Comment: @Simon in any event, because Harry still has the Trace on him and the Ministry was at that time corrupt, I expect that they still would have used it should he have used any magic irrespective of his setting

Comment: @N_Soong Oh yes, I completely agree that at the time in universe it would have been impossible for him to practice magic outside of Hogwarts. I just wanted to make it known that young Witches and Wizards likely could practice spells at home, given a magical parentage. (Perhaps this is what leads to the whole Pure Blood is better, as they can practice where as muggle borns cannot)